# Roslyn-get return statement of a method c#

Tags: c#, roslyn

With the below code I am able to get the references of a method. Now I want to get the return statements of this method. I know I should use ReturnStatementSyntax. I am new to Roslyn so not sure how should to get return statements of a method.

```
public List<ReferencedSymbol> Find(string solutionPath, string methodName)
        {
            var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
            InvocationExpressionSyntax node = null;
            ISymbol symbol = null;
            bool flag = false;
            foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
            {
                foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                {
                    var model = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
                    var methodInvocation = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
                    node = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
                        .Where(x => ((MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)x.Expression).Name.ToString() == methodName)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    //I am not sure how should I get return statement for a method using ReturnStatementSyntax
                    var returnStatement = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<ReturnStatementSyntax>().ToList();
                    if (node == null) 
                        continue;
                    symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (flag) break;
            }

            return SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(symbol, solution).Result.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this with LINQ.
Assume you have a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`variable called `method`, the code should be:

```
var returnStatement = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<ReturnStatementSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
```

However, in your code, I see no signs of `MethodDeclarationSyntax`. You can get the method that you want by using LINQ.
Also, please don't call `.Result`. Either make your method async or use non async overloads. For example, instead of `.GetRootAsync()`, use `.GetRoot()`

Comment: Beware that this will return the wrong node for local functions or lambdas.